How do you install FTL mod Multiverse & Hyperspace on KDE Neon?
I'm attempting to install the Multiverse/Hyperspace expansion for the game Faster Than Light (FTL) on my KDE Neon system. I've already purchased and installed FTL through Steam. I found an updated guide for installing the expansion on Linux systems, which can be found here.
However, I encountered an issue on step 39 where I received an error stating "hyperspace.xml not found." It seems that the hyperspace.xml file is supposed to be located within the hyperspace.ftl file mentioned in step 21. On my system, the share folder appears to be located under ~/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/, and the FTL folder is ~/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/FTL Faster Than Light/.
Below is a summarized version of the steps I followed from the installation guide:

Launch FTL to ensure the correct version is running (1.6.13).
Download Hyperspace FTL-Hyperspace.x.x.x.zip and Vhati’s Slipstream 1.9.1 for Linux.
Extract specific files from the Hyperspace zip file into the FTL data folder.
Modify the FTL executable file with certain export lines.
Extract the SlipstreamModManager_1.9.1-Unix.tar.gz and move Hyperspace.ftl into the mods folder.
Launch Slipstream and patch Hyperspace.
Disable Steam Cloud sync and remove old saves to avoid compatibility issues.
Step 39 is where I run FTL from steam.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on resolving the error and successfully installing the FTL Multiverse/Hyperspace expansion on KDE Neon. Thank you in advance for your assistance.
